# How do you make a wither unable to break blocks?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

What is the command to make a wither called 1 unable to break blocks or summon a wither called 1 that cannot break blocks?

Edit:

So far I have made the wither stay in a certain location and face in a certain direction using the teleport command. It works fine and doesn't break anything but when I load up the world it destroys everything and goes back to normal which means I have to manually fix everything every time. I am open to other suggestions, anything that works.

Comment: What have you tried? Please, show some effort when asking a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This is just not possible on this edition.

This is not possible using just commands as Bedrock Edition is well known for not allowing NBT data in commands, meaning that tags like `{NoAI:1b}` or something would not work, nor will you be able to summon one with a custom name, these have to be applied by nametag. Sorry to disappoint.